# Add sub activites with tab activiy

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

How to add different activities with tab activity, for example i have many tab like home, add music, add video etc, home tab attach with home activity. In home activity there is a button , after clicking this button page will go to another activity, So how can i see tab to this activity.

Answer (score 1):

As Anrijs said TabActivity has been deprecated on android so use the support design library's [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Then create a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then implement a [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) for each of your activities

And follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) tutorial to make everything work nicely

Comment: if i do without fragments, so how can i do.....

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity is was deprecated in API level 13. You should consider using ViewPager and TabLayout.

Add Design Support library to your project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Add TabLayout and ViewPager to you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Create fragment:

```
// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
       return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Create FragmentPageAdapter:

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Set up Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
        MainActivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Source: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers will not be of any use if the external linked page changes in future

Comment: i have done layout , so please suggest me how can i do without fragment